# Click event doesn't fire on pages other than first

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

i am using the DataTable plugin to display data in my backend page. The plugin works so far very good except in one situation: I have a table showing all products. For each line of the table i have a link for AJAX activation / deactivation of one product. If i am on the first page the activation / deactivation works fine, but when i choose another page using the DataTable Pagination i cannot activate / deactivate the chosen product. It does not display any error in the Firebug, so i am assuming that somehow the link is not correctly displayed.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table id="products" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Copy</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Copy</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><a href="http://deals/admin/products/edit/1">Iphone</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://deals/admin/products/copy/1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></a></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-href="1" class="status_product"><span id="span_1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span></a></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-href="1" class="delete_product"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and right after the HTML code, comes the Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#products').DataTable();
    $('table#products td a.status_product').click(function() {
        // activate / deactivate
    });
    $('table#delTable tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation by providing selector as a second argument in [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) call, see example below:

```
$('table#products').on('click', 'a.status_product', function() {
    // activate / deactivate
});
```

From jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

See "Direct and delegated events" in jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation and [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more information.